# xcode ios: in cell image overlaps on the label

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am displaying an image on my cell in the table. I have the code within

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

While I am using storyboard, so I displayed the image in the cell with

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_lotImagesArray[row]];
```

However, when I tried to load the image from a webserver, The image sits on top of the label in the cell (blocking the label text)

The code I used to display the image from webserver is this:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.domainhere.com/images/%@", lotPhoto[row]];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strURL ];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Can someone please advice where did I go wrong?

Comment: In the storyboard, did you make sure your `UIImageView` isn't overlapping over the `UILabel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of likely possibilities:

**First**, you might want to double-check to make sure that you have

```
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

If you don't, when it sizes the image to fit in the `UIImageView`, the image can bleed over the bounds of the image view. I notice this problem, especially, when I'm doing this image loading in a background queue.

**Second**, if you're setting the `imageView` property of the `UITableViewCell` in the background (like the simplified sample code below), you should know that it's important to properly initialize the image with a blank image before you kick off the background image loading process. So, an example of very common code when loading a cell from a web based source is something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = ... // you configure your cell however you want

    // make sure you do this next line to configure the image view

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blankthumbnail.png"];

    // now let's go to the web to get the image

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{

        UIImage *image = ... // do the time consuming process to download the image

        // if we successfully got an image, remember, ALWAYS update the UI in the main queue
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // let's make sure the cell is still visible (i.e. hasn't scrolled off the screen)
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if (cell)
            {
                cell.imageView.image = image;
                cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            }
        });
    });

    return cell;
}
```

Clearly, if you do something like that, you'll want to make sure that the `[UIImage imageNamed:@"blankthumbnail.png"];` is not returning `nil` (i.e. make sure your app is successfully finding it in the bundle). Common problems might include failure to have a blank image at all, a mistake in the name, failure to include the image in your Target settings, under the "Build Phases" tab, under "Copy Bundle Resources".

**Third**, you need to make sure that when you're using subclassed `UITableViewCell` entries, that you don't use the standard `UITableViewCell` property names of `imageView`, `textLabel`, etc. Make sure to use your own, unique names. If you use `imageView`, the system gets confused between your new `IBOutlet` and the default `imageView` property of the `UITableViewCell`.